# How to use ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory to save each class/label in other subfolders?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

Edit:
Setup:

```
Win 10 x64
Python 3.8.7
TF version 2.4.0
Keras version 2.4.3 #not needed I think but
```

I have dataset with images with structure like:

```
dataset/
  class1/
    img1class1.jpg
    ...
  class2/
    img1class2.jpg
    ...
```

And I'm using `flow_from_directory` method from `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` with options like:

```
gen = imgen.flow_from_directory(
  'dataset/',
  target_size = (160, 120),
  batch_size = 25,
  class_mode = 'binary',
  save_to_dir = 'new_dataset/',
  save_prefix = 'new',
  save_format = 'jpg'
)
```

But it is putting every images from every classes into one folder `new_dataset/`

```
new_dataset/
  new1.jpg #while that could be from class 1
  new2.jpg # and that from class 2
  ...
```

Is it possible to 'force' `flow_from_directory` to make folders structure to be:

```
new_dataset/
  class1/
    new1.jpg
    ...
  class2/
    new1.jpg
    ...
```

Is it also possible that batch_size will be having only images 'created' from one specific img, I mean that `img1class1.jpg` will be in whole batch but with other transformations?
I want to do sth like 25 new images from 1 old image.

Sorry for my Eng, I wish u understand (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 'workaround', so here it goes:

```
import os

labels = {}

for i, one_class in enumerate(os.listdir('dataset')):
  gen = idg.flow_from_directory(
    'dataset',
    target_size = (160, 120),
    batch_size = 25,
    class_mode = 'binary',
    classes = [one_class],
    save_to_dir = f'dataset/{one_class}',
    save_prefix = 'new_image',
    save_format = 'jpg'
  )

  ...
  
  labels[one_class] = i #If u need them...
```